# How to add programatically timer and other controls with source code VB.net

Tags: vb.net, forms

I want to specify in a text field how many timers I want to add to my form and specify the code that should be into the timer.

For instance: My textbox says "2" and then I click a button and it creates two timers and adds a specific source code for both timers.

I have tried different codes and while they worked, I wasn't able to specify the number of controls on a form to create.

How can I achieve this efficiently?

Thanks

Comment: Please check: [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You are a little confusing. You need to clarify your question. Do you want to make timers, or controls, or visible timers that count or count down time for user?

Comment: I want to create one timer dynamically (when I click on a button, the timer gets created). And that timer should have a specific source code in it like "Msgbox("Timerrr!!")"

Answer (score 3):

Just to create one timer

```
Public Class Form1
  private _timer as Windows.Forms.Timer
  ...

  Public Sub New()
    ...
    _timer = New Timer(Me)
    _timer.Interval = 1000 'Timer will trigger one second after start
    AddHandler _timer.tick, AddressOf Timer_tick 'Timer will call this sub when done
  End Sub

  Sub Button_click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
    _timer.Start() 'Start the timer
    ...
  End Sub

  Private Sub Timer_tick(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
     MessageBox.Show("Timerrr!!")
  End Sub
  ...
End Class
```

Now if you want to create more than one timer, you can use an array of Timer.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I used a form conatining a NumericUpDown controll element, a button and a label, plus two labels which only contain text.[See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnFDR.png)

To create the timers, I use the function `add_timers(timercount)`, which looks like this:

```
Function add_timers(timercount As Integer)
    'Using a loop to creat <timercount> timers
    For g As Integer = 1 To timercount
        'Creating new timer 't'
        Dim t As New Timer()
        'setting interval of t
        t.Interval = 1000
        'Enabling timer
        t.Enabled = True
        'Code which runs when t ticks
        AddHandler t.Tick, AddressOf TimerTick
    Next
End Function
```

This function gets called when `Button1`, the start button gets pressed. It uses `NumericUpDown1.Value` as the parameter for the function. The function uses a loop to create new timers `t`, sets their intervals and the code to run when they tick.

Unfourtunately, I didn't find a way to dynamically create code, so every timer performs the same action. Using arrays and loops in a clever way might enable you to use different value for each timer. To create code for the timer use a Sub:

```
Sub TimerTick(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Add your code here
    Label1.Text += 1
End Sub
```

The complete code I use is:

```
Public Class Form1

    Function add_timers(timercount As Integer)
        'Using a loop to creat <timercount> timers
        For g As Integer = 1 To timercount
            'Creating new timer 't'
            Dim t As New Timer()
            'setting interval of t
            t.Interval = 1000
            'Enabling timer
            t.Enabled = True
            'Code which runs when t ticks
            AddHandler t.Tick, AddressOf TimerTick
        Next
   End Function

    Sub TimerTick(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'Add your code here
        Label1.Text += 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        add_timers(NumericUpDown1.Value)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Packing the timers into an array is possible, that way you can easily access each timer with its index. Serach for it on the internet, and if you then have no idea of how to do it, tell me in the comments.

Comment: This looks good but I need to be addressing the different timer instances. For instance I want to do something with my second timer and the third (like disable them etc.), how would I call them up? How can I name my timers and start them in the code above?

Comment: I am racking my brains about your comment with the "access each timer with its index" - How?! The thing is this: I need each new timer to have a number whcih increments like

The first timer -> "timer1", the second "timer2" this way i could access them. 
THEN, I want to give out from within each timer the number of the timer to the TimerTick(CurrentNoOfTimer As Integer) so that it does slightly different things for each timer that calls the function

Comment: You can acces the timers in  The ARRAY with their indexes.